# Default Value for report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying too see how *JasperReports Server* gets the default value set in a report.  I know how to set a default value in *iReport*, but I'm trying to come with a way to check for that value programmatically in *Java*.

In particular, I'm interested in a List of Values Single Value Radio Select, I am using a Resource Descriptor to get other Report data, but this seems to elude me.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To set default value in case of null, you can do this

```
 ((!$F{field_name} == null) ? '0' : $F{field_name})
```

To get parameter type you can do

```
JRParameter[] params = jasperReport.getParameters();

for(JRParameter param : params) {
     param.getName();
     param.getDescription();
     param.getDefaultValueExpression();
     param.getNestedType(); // get parameter type that can be list, string
}
```

For detailed reference regarding Resource Descriptor you can check, they have given complete example  http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-5-0/JasperServer-Web-Services-Guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!  Sorry it has taken me so long to reply back.  Is there away to get this info using the REST api?